# How to apply rotationEffect in SwiftUI in both clockwise & anticlockwise directions?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to animate a bell icon with the rotation effect but it only animates with the specified angle one way:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var alarmSet = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.black
            VStack {
                Image(systemName: "bell.fill")
                    .font(.system(size: 250))
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .rotationEffect(.degrees(reminderSet ? 10 : 0), anchor: .top)
                    .animation(.interpolatingSpring(mass: 0.5, stiffness: 170, damping: 2.5, initialVelocity: 0), value: alarmSet)
                Button(action: {
                        alarmSet.toggle()
                }, label: {
                    Text(alarmSet ? "Alarm Set" : "Wake Me")
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .foregroundStyle(.white)
                })
                .padding(.top, 20)
            }
            .background(.black)
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}
```

With the code above, the bell animates between the left side & center, I'd like to get it to

1. swing with the same angle towards the right as well
2. swing this way thrice in total and settle to the resting state. The interpolating spring animation causes the bell to swing more than thrice as it comes to its resting state. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: A phaseAnimator or keyFrameAnimator might be ways to get this working, but they both require iOS 17. Which iOS version do you need to support?

Comment: @BenzyNeez iOS 17 is good enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`keyframeAnimator`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/keyframeanimator(initialvalue:trigger:content:keyframes:)?changes=_5) (iOS 17+)

```
Image(systemName: "bell.fill")
    .font(.system(size: 250))
    .foregroundColor(.white)
    .keyframeAnimator(initialValue: Angle.zero, trigger: alarmSet) { content, value in
        content.rotationEffect(value, anchor: .top)
    } keyframes: { _ in
        KeyframeTrack {
            let spring = Spring(mass: 0.5, stiffness: 170, damping: 2.5)
            SpringKeyframe(Angle.degrees(10), duration: 0.05, spring: spring)
            // Consider putting this part in a for loop if there are a lot of bounces
            SpringKeyframe(Angle.degrees(-10), duration: 0.1, spring: spring)
            SpringKeyframe(Angle.degrees(10), duration: 0.1, spring: spring)
            SpringKeyframe(Angle.degrees(-10), duration: 0.1, spring: spring)
            SpringKeyframe(Angle.degrees(10), duration: 0.1, spring: spring)
            // the last frame should have start velocity 0 so that it goes back to the initial position
            SpringKeyframe(Angle.zero, duration: 0.05, spring: spring, startVelocity: Angle.zero)
        }
    }
```

Also consider using some of the [built-in springs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/spring).

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
withAnimation {
    raiseTheBell = true //  Move the bell to the falling state
} completion: {
    withAnimation(.interpolatingSpring(mass: 0.5, stiffness: 170, damping: 2.5, initialVelocity: 0)) {
        raiseTheBell = false //  Release the bell when reached to the highest position
    }
}
alarmSet.toggle() //  Not same as the bell animation trigger
```

[image: Demo]

Comment: I see an issue here wherein setting the state to false again also changes the button text instead of toggling it to alarm set/not set. Also, is it possible to limit the swing animation to exactly thrice instead of it reducing gradually?

Comment: About the title, use another state for the title and a separate one for the animation. The code has been updated to demo this as well.

Comment: And about the number if chimes, spring uses physics for animations and its more realistic, you can do key frame based animations to have more control over the animation. Probably with [KeyframeTimeline](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/keyframetimeline)

Answer (score 1):

There are probably a number of ways to achieve this effect, some simpler than others.

One way is just to use a second (basic) animation moving in the opposite direction. The speed and extent of the movement, as well as the number of swings, can all be tweaked by changing the parameters to the `.interpolatingSpring` animation and/or the size of the angle.

```swift
Image(systemName: "bell.fill")
    .font(.system(size: 250))
    .foregroundColor(.white)
    .rotationEffect(.degrees(alarmSet ? -5 : 5), anchor: .top)
    .animation(.interpolatingSpring(mass: 2, stiffness: 180, damping: 8, initialVelocity: 15), value: alarmSet)
    .rotationEffect(.degrees(alarmSet ? 5 : -5), anchor: .top)
    .animation(.easeOut, value: alarmSet)
```

[image: Animation]